# Switch among states in ui-router without clicks

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to angular and ui-router.

I have implemented some sample like this.

```
    $stateProvider
    .state('route1', {
        url: "/route1",
        templateUrl: "route1.html"
    })

    .state('route2', {
        url: "/route2",
        templateUrl: "route2.html"
    })
```

This is working fine, but it requires a click.

What I am going to do is, the pages will automatically change among different states.
And it would start the loop from the first page if it reached the end.

Just like a slider.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to change state via `$state.go('route1')` (see docs http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state). So in your controller you can use, f.e. $timeout and change state.